# How to understand 2-d array method

Tags: java

I am having trouble understanding what the following code performs.

```
public void createBuckets(int numOfBuckets){

    for(int i=0; i < numOfBuckets; i++){
      buckets[i] = new Bucket("Bucket" + (i + 1), 3);}
}
```

I understand that "buckets" is an array that itself, should contain arrays.
But I am having trouble understanding what "new" signifies in this context, and what everything in the bracket ("Bucket" + (i + 1), 3) does. Thanks alot for any possible help.

Comment: It creates a `Bucket` object and saves it into `buckets` array, I assume that `Bucket` constructor gets a name and capacity..

Comment: `buckets` does NOT contain arrays, it contains `Bucket` objects. Bucket` is a class. `new Bucket` is creating a new instance of that class. You need to look at the declaration for that class.

Comment: If this is a bucket as in `HashMap` then the bucket will **contain** an array - it will not **be** an array.

Comment: `i + 1` will be appended to the String "Bucket", in the first iteration you'll have "Bucket1` as the name, in the second "Bucket2" and so on..

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, `buckets` is not a 2D array (assuming that your code compiles). It's a 1D array containing references to `Bucket` objects.

```
buckets[i] = new Bucket("Bucket" + (i + 1), 3);
```

assigns a new Bucket object to the `i`th index of the array.

`Bucket` has a constructor that accepts a String and an int. Your loop is equivalent to :

```
buckets[0] = new Bucket("Bucket1",3);
buckets[1] = new Bucket("Bucket2",3);
buckets[2] = new Bucket("Bucket3",3);
...
buckets[numOfBuckets-1] = new Bucket("Bucket"+numOfBuckets,3);
```

Comment: Right, and a `Bucket` seems to be initialized with String (it's name) and an int (it's size?). There are certainly further operations to insert something into the buckets, which might explain further.

Answer (score 1):

`new` creates an instance of Bucket and adds it to array of Bucket instances.

`"Bucket" + (i + 1)` and `3` are arguments that `Bucket` constructor takes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, buckets is an uninitialized array of the Bucket type. In Java, object arrays are uninitialized (their elements are set to null). So when you say Bucket[] buckets = new Bucket[10], the buckets array will contain 10 null values.

The purpose of createBuckets is to actually create the buckets, so that the buck